# Add key value to all objects in array from another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wanted to add a key:value parameter to all the objects in an array from another array
eg:

```
var arrOfObj = [{id: 001, date:'22/05/2020', Actor:'jane'},
                {id: 002, date:'02/03/2020', Actor:'alice'},
                {id: 003, date:'11/06/2020', Actor:'jean'},
                {id: 004, date:'20/01/2020', Actor:'yann'}];

var arrayScore = [44,2,3,5];
```

I want add for every objects a key:value parameter from arrayScore, like :

```
var arrOfObj = [{id: 001, date:'22/05/2020', Actor:'jane', score:44},
                {id: 002, date:'02/03/2020', Actor:'alice', score:2},
                {id: 003, date:'11/06/2020', Actor:'jean', score:3},
                {id: 004, date:'20/01/2020', Actor:'yann', score:5}];
```

I tried this code:

```
    var result = arrOfObj.map(function(el) {
                     var o = Object.assign({}, el);
                     o.score = arrayScore;
                     return o;
                     });
   console.log(result);
```

but `arrOfObj` add all values from `arrayScore` for every object!!
How can I change this please??

Thank you for your HELP!

Comment: Are your `id` values really numbers, or are they strings? If they're numbers, I strongly recommend **not** using the legacy octal format to write them. If they're meant to be strings, put them in quotes.

Comment: `arrOfObj.map((item, idx) => { item.score = arrayScore[idx]; return item; })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the new array including the user scores, I would also take note of [TJCrowders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s point about the Ids.

```js
var arrOfObj = [{id: 1, date:'22/05/2020', Actor:'jane'},
                {id: 2, date:'02/03/2020', Actor:'alice'},
                {id: 3, date:'11/06/2020', Actor:'jean'},
                {id: 4, date:'20/01/2020', Actor:'yann'}];

var arrayScore = [44,2,3,5];

const result = arrOfObj.map((el, index) => ({...el, score: arrayScore[index] }));
console.log("Result with scores:", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need a new array of objects, but only need to add the properties to the objects in the array, you can use the array method forEach instead of map.

If we pass two parameters to the callback provided to forEach, the second parameter will receive the index of the array element we are iterating over. This allows us to assign the corresponding value from the arrayScore array.

This should work

```
arrOfObj.forEach((o, i) => {
    o.score = arrayScore[i];
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @camelCaseForTheWin, welcome to SO. Please consider adding some explanation of how your code works/why it works. Simply providing the code might not be enough for people to understand. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @GBra, I hope my edit improved the response.